# Designing function deriving weighted average in R

Tags: r, function

I am designing a function dividing the case if they have duplicated values or not. If so, they should come up with the table, sorted values of unique ones, sorted values of duplicated ones, means of the vector, means of the unique values and duplicated values and finally the weighted value. Plz take a look at this code, and let me know which point is wrong here.

```
avg<-function(...){
  x<-c(...)
  cond<-duplicated(x)
  if (any(cond)) {
    table(x)
    sort(unique(x))
    sort(x[cond==T])
    mean(x)
    mean(unique(x))
    mean(sort(x[cond==T])) 
    for(i in 1:length(unique(x))) {
      sort(unique(x))[i]*(as.integer(table(x))[i]/length(x))
    }
  } else{sum(x)/length(x)
  }
}

avg(2,4,3,1,2,1)
```

Comment: Please provide an example of your desired output. For example, what result should avg(2,4,3,1,2,1) return?

Comment: Oh it should return the table of c(2,3,4,1,2,1), sort it in ascending order with unique values(1 2 3 4), duplicated values should be printed in ascending order (1 2), mean (13/6), mean of duplicated values(1.5), and weighted average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the problems with your code is that each of the calculations made when there are any duplications are overwritten.  The following code returns a named list of solutions:

```
   weighted.average <- function(x){
  
  t <- table(x)
  t.values <- as.integer(names(t))
  frequency <- as.integer(t)
  weights <- frequency/length(x)
  sum(weights * t.values)

}

avg<-function(...){
  x<-c(...)
  cond<-duplicated(x)
  if (any(cond)) {
    
    return_value <- list("Table_x" = table(x),
                         "unique_x" = sort(unique(x)),
                         "duplicated_x" = sort(x[cond==T]),
                         "mean_x" = mean(x),
                         "mean_unique_x" = mean(unique(x)),
                         "mean_duplicated_x" = mean(sort(x[cond==T])),
                        "weighted_average" = weighted.average(x)
                        )
    } else {
    
    return_value <- sum(x)/length(x)
    
    }

  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! By the way, is there any way that I can come up with my own function calculating weighted average?

Comment: I revised my answer to fix a nit and to add a new function -- weighted average.